# MVC routing Index/id actions goes to server root

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, routes, iis-7.5

If I have an ActionLink which points to **Server/Site/Prices/Index/24**, (with *Prices* being the controller and *Index* being the Action) what it actually does is navigate to **Server/24**, which obviously provides a 404.  The same thing if I go to **Server/Site/Options/Index/15**,(with *Options* being the controller and *Index* being the Action) what it actually does is navigate to **Server/15**.

I find it even more strange that it is going to the server root, not the site root.

This works fine running IIS Express on my dev machine.  However on the server it is acting strange when navigating to actions called **Index**.  I'm using VS2013 Publish to deploy.
If I change the Index Action name to something different, then that will work

I initially thought this was just a single controller issue, but then came across another controller Index action doing the same thing.

My RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

My action links look like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Options and Prices", "Index", "Prices", new { id = option.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" })
```

To add to this, if I deploy to a different server and it works correctly.  Also works fine locally with IIS Express.  Suggests it's some IIS setting somewhere.

Comment: can we see your actionlink? Also, what's witht he {name} part in your route config?

Comment: Server/Site/Prices/Index/24. Can you mention controller, action and parameters in that url ?

Comment: @jbutler483 Edited to add actionlink. The {name} is about providing a nice display name for the id, but the problem exists with that there or not in the route.  I will remove to avoid confusion.    
JeevaJsb Now added note What is the controller and action.

Comment: Instead of default try more specific.
 routes.MapRoute(
                "ServerSite", // Route name
                "Prices/Index/{id }", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Prices", action = "Index", Id= UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

Comment: You knew this, but anyway aware of this, this should be placed before the default route..

Comment: what is "Server/Site"? Is this host name ? or any folder ? or url prefix ?

Comment: @JeevaJsb "Server/Site" is the hosting server & site in IIS.  Eg http://Apps.com/MyApplication/Prices/Index   I've never had to get involved with adding extra routes like that before, which leads me to believe the problem is being masked.

Comment: As suggested @JeevaJsb - If add this - then it makes no difference.  routes.MapRoute(
 name: "PricesIndex",
 url: "Prices/Index/{id}",
 defaults: new { controller = "Prices", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);

Comment: Interestingly if I go straight to **Server/Site/Prices/Index/** then the page doesn't redirect - only with an id specified.